# docker-compose java cannot access jarfile

Tags: java, shell, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot app as one of the services in a Docker Compose setup, but whenever I run `docker-compose up -d` the container running the Spring Boot app fails and exits immediately. For purposes of this post I'm using generic names like "mycontainer" and "myfile".

Running `docker-compose logs core` shows that the error message is:

`mycontainer | Error: unable to access jarfile myjar.jar`

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  webapp:
    image: webapp_image
    container_name: webapp-container
    build:
      context: ./webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './webapp:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 35729:35729
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - env_file=./webapp/.env

  core:
    image: core_image
    container_name: core-container
    build:
      context: ./core
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './core:/usr/src/core'
      - './algorithms:/usr/src/algorithms'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - JARFILE=myjar.jar
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

The Dockerfile for the `core` service, which is the one running the Spring Boot app, is this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/core
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/algorithms
ADD ./myproject/target/myjar.jar /usr/src/core
ADD ./algorithms /usr/src/algorithms
WORKDIR /usr/src/core

CMD java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar $JARFILE
```

If I run an individual container from the `core_image` image, and set the same environment vars that I defined in the docker-compose file, I can launch the Spring Boot app successfully, like so:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name mycontainer core_image sh
$ /usr/src/core # ls -l
total 15852
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      16228579 Apr 21 22:44 myjar.jar
$ /usr/src/core # java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar $JARFILE
```

But if I run a container from the same image as part of `docker-compose up -d` the container fails with the error that Java couldn't access the jarfile. I've tried specifying the absolute path to the jarfile in the `CMD` of the Dockerfile, but that doesn't help when running from Docker Compose.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I'm on a Windows 10 host. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are overriding content of /usr/src/core [where you copy the jar file to] by mounting content from ./core in docker-compose. Remove below mount from services->core->volumes and give a try.

  `volumes:
      - './core:/usr/src/core'`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I had already realized that the problem was that the jarfile wasn't where I thought it was (got misled by the fact it was there when running a standalone container -- but there I wasn't mounting volumes), but I didn't get a chance to answer my own question. :)

Comment: Thanks, bro for this answer, it was what made me confuse why it is not working.